# How to serialize virtual attributes in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I want to searilaize a couple of virtual attribute defined in my model like below

```
class User
  attribute :full_name, :string
  attribute :mobile,    :integer
  serialize :properties
end
```

I wants to save `full_name` and `mobile` in hash format in properties column of users table. How can I do that, Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save those two attributes in your `properties` column you'll have to first make sure that your `properties` column is a text column. Then add the following to your `User` model.

`serialize :properties, Hash`

Then add a callback to make sure that the attributes are built correctly:

```
before_save :serialize_properties

private

def serialize_properties
  properties = { full_name: full_name, mobile: mobile }
end
```